# Passing bash variables not working

Tags: bash

I have the following set in bash:

```
 export chain_dir='~/.eris/chains/simplechain'
```

This works

```
 echo $chain_dir
 ~/.eris/chains/simplechain
```

Then try I try to use it with ls and I get:

```
 ls $chain_dir
 ls: cannot access ~/.eris/chains/simplechain: No such file or directory
```

But cut and paste the same directory string as in $chain_dir and it works:

```
 ~/.eris/chains/simplechain
 accounts.csv  addresses.csv  simplechain_full_000  simplechain_root_000
```

I believe that I am missing something:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` isnt expanded into your home dir before giving it to `ls`.

Use `$HOME` or

let`eval` do the expansion for you
   `$var1='~/.config/'`
   `$ls $(eval echo "$var1")`

Comment: There's *really* no need for `eval`; `~` is expanded if it's the first character of the assigned value and not quoted: `var1=~/.config`.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` isn't expanded to your home directory path before being passed to `ls`.

I would suggest writing it out in full, `/home/user/`, or using `$HOME`:

```
export chain_dir="$HOME/.eris/chains/simplechain"
```

Note the use of double quotes around the string.

Answer (score 0):

`~` isn't being expanded because you quoted it. Leave it outside the quotes, and `bash` will expand it before performing the assignment. Notice that you can quote the *rest* of the path if necessary, as long as the `~` is outside the quotes.

```
$ chain_dir=~'/.eris/chains/simplechain'
$ echo "$chain_dir"
/home/tbrooke/.eris/chains/simplechain
```

(Assuming `/home/tbrooke` is your home directory.)